# Taylor series and singularities of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I have been struggling with the following problem. I have the function $$f(z)=\frac{e^{z}}{(z-1)cos(\pi z)}$$  I want to find all the singularities. It is easy to see that this function has an editable singularity at $z=1$ but I don't know what happens when $z=n$ odd integer number. I would like to find the Taylor series of $f(z)$ around $z=0$.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: $\cos\pi z=0$ iff $z=n+1/2$ with $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(z)=\frac{e^{z}}{(z-1)\cos(\pi z)}$$ Around $z=0$, we have
$$f(z)=\frac{1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{6}+\frac{z^4}{24}+O\left(
   z^{5}\right) }{(z-1)\left(1-\frac{\pi ^2 z^2}{2}+\frac{\pi ^4 z^4}{24}+O\left(z^{6}\right) \right)}$$
Now, long division to get
$$f(z)=1+2 z+\frac{1}{2} \left(5+\pi ^2\right) z^2+\left(\frac{8}{3}+\pi ^2\right)
   z^3+\frac{5}{24} \left(13+6 \pi ^2+\pi ^4\right) z^4+O\left(z^5\right)$$

Comment: Yeah exactly. I compared it with wolfram alpha and it is correct. I have obtained the same result using the standard derivation method. I want to ask how to get the Laurent expansion at the ring $|z-1|<1/2$. I have deduced that $e^{z}=e e^{z-1}$ and $\cos(\pi z)=-\cos(\pi(z-1))$. What kind the relations are between the coeficcients of this Laurent expansion and the one  do it in  $1/2<|z-1|<3/2$?